# Mobile Phone offline maindenhead or mgrs web app

Tags: aprs, echolink, location, dx, maidenhead-locator

I read an article in a magazine or online about a (.gov, I think) site which showed two, four to six character sequences in a mobile phone browser window. The letters from left to right indicated lower to higher precision positioning. As precision decreased, the characters on the right turned red, indicating a best guess accuracy.

There wasn't an app to install. It was a web page where you would visit it once while on 4G/WiFi, let it download some data to your phone (I think it was an HTML5 web app), then it could be used offline, so long as you had a GPS signal.

I'm going on a trip soon and I'd like to use this app, but I forget what the website was. I saw it within the last year. Does anyone have any clue what the site could be? It could have used maidenhead or MGRS, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: So, your question is `"what website did I see, but can't remember?"` -- or is your question `"I like to know if there is an app which can display the maidenhead locator on my mobile phone?"` -- if the later then please specify what mobile phone you are using.

Comment: The former. I was curious to see if anyone else has come across the same site.

Comment: OK, I am out, I seriously _do not know what you don't know nor can remember_ :-)

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a long shot. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of off-network travel and one thing I found out is that you can [cache Google Maps as described on this link](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

Then your Google Maps app will keep running as long as you have GPS (and if you don't you likely have bigger problems).